# Why user.is_active is false if the username and password are stored in the database?

Tags: python, django, authentication, runtime-error, frame

Every time I try to log in in the website I created, it returns the else in the user_login function in views.py, but I don't understand why since it stores correctly in Users in the database.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .forms import UserForm



# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'app1/index.html')

@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

def register(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            
            registered = True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors)
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()

    return render(request, 'app1/register.html',{'user_form':user_form, 'registered':registered})

def user_login(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Account Not Active")
        else:
            print("Someone tried to login and failed")
            print(f"Username: {username} and password {password}")
            return HttpResponse ("Invalid Login details supplied")
    
    else:
        return render(request, 'app1/login.html',)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email', 'password')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

login.html

```
{% extends 'app1/base.html' %}
{% block body_block %}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Please Login</h1>
    <form action="{% url 'app1:user_login' %}" method="POST">

        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name = "usuario" placeholder = "enter username">

        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="contra">

        <input type="submit" value="Login">
        
        


    </form>
</div>




{% endblock %}
```

So please, if someone see an error in my code please notify me, because I'm literally blocked with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

authenticate methods takes in request as first argument.

```
def user_login(request):
   
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')
    
            # user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
            user = authenticate(request, username = username, password = password)
    
            if user:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
                else:
                    return HttpResponse("Account Not Active")
            else:
                print("Someone tried to login and failed")
                print(f"Username: {username} and password {password}")
                return HttpResponse ("Invalid Login details supplied")
        
        else:
            return render(request, 'app1/login.html',)
```

And as first answer suggests password (not password1) and password2 are not required args you only need password to set password how you validate it is upto you.

Edit

```
<form action="{% url 'app1:user_login' %}" method="POST">

{% csrf_token %}
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"placeholder = "enter username">

<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: You were submitting empty form. Sorry I didnt see it before. I have edited the answer. I would suggest you to learn more about how forms work with django.

Comment: Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that you are missing a required field. Required fields are: username, password1 and password2. You need two password fields so that it can be validated (i.e. to check that the same password is filled in on both fields).

Here is the relevant documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/

Comment: It still shows me the invalid else:

class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email', 'password1','password2')